# Octave : logistic regression : difference between fmincg and fminunc

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I often use `fminunc` for a logistic regression problem.  I have read on web that [Andrew Ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng) uses `fmincg` instead of `fminunc`, with same arguments.  The results are different, and often `fmincg` is more exact, but not too much. (I am comparing the results of fmincg function fminunc against the same data)

So, my question is : what is the difference between these two functions?  What algorithm does each function have implemented?  (Now, I just use these functions without knowing exactly how they work).

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is `fmincg`? It's not in octave core and is also not in any of the Forge packages.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You will have to look inside the code of `fmincg` because it is not part of Octave. After some search I found that it's a function file provided by the Machine Learning class of Coursera as part of the homework. Read the comments and answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770934/matlabs-fminsearch-different-from-octaves-fmincg) for a discussion about the algorithms.

Comment: Oh. thanks :) I don't notice that has a file in fmincg in my folder. thanks so much

Comment: The comment of that question told nothing about `fmincg`; they were only discussing `fminsearch` which is not related to this question. @emrea's answer suggests that `fmincg` is implementing [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Answer (score 25):

In contrast to other answers here suggesting the primary difference between fmincg and fminunc is accuracy or speed, perhaps the most important difference for some applications is memory efficiency. In programming exercise 4 (i.e., Neural Network Training) of Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class at Coursera, the comment in ex4.m about fmincg is

> %% =================== Part 8: Training NN ===================
>   %  You have now implemented all the code necessary to train a neural
>   %  network. To train your neural network, we will now use "fmincg", which
>   %  is a function which works similarly to "fminunc". Recall that these
>   %  advanced optimizers are able to train our cost functions efficiently as
>   %  long as we provide them with the gradient computations.

Like the original poster, I was also curious about how the results of ex4.m might differ using fminunc instead of fmincg. So I tried to replace the fmincg call

```
options = optimset('MaxIter', 50);
[nn_params, cost] = fmincg(costFunction, initial_nn_params, options);
```

with the following call to fminunc

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);
[nn_params, cost, exit_flag] = fminunc(costFunction, initial_nn_params, options);
```

but got the following error message from a 32-bit build of Octave running on Windows:

> error: memory exhausted or requested size too large for range of Octave's index
>   type -- trying to return to prompt

A 32-bit build of MATLAB running on Windows provides a more detailed error message:

> Error using find
>   Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
>   Error in spones (line 14)
>   [i,j] = find(S);
>   Error in color (line 26)
>   J = spones(J);
>   Error in sfminbx (line 155)
>       group = color(Hstr,p);
>   Error in fminunc (line 408)
>      [x,FVAL,~,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,GRAD,HESSIAN] = sfminbx(funfcn,x,l,u, ...
>   Error in ex4 (line 205)
>   [nn_params, cost, exit_flag] = fminunc(costFunction, initial_nn_params, options);

The MATLAB memory command on my laptop computer reports:

> Maximum possible array:            2046 MB (2.146e+09 bytes) *
>   Memory available for all arrays:   3402 MB (3.568e+09 bytes) **
>   Memory used by MATLAB:              373 MB (3.910e+08 bytes)
>   Physical Memory (RAM):             3561 MB (3.734e+09 bytes)
>   *  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
>   ** Limited by virtual address space available.

I previously was thinking that Professor Ng chose to use fmincg to train the ex4.m neural network (that has 400 input features, 401 including the bias input) to increase the training speed. However, now I believe his reason for using fmincg was to increase the memory efficiency enough to allow the training to be performed on 32-bit builds of Octave/MATLAB. A short discussion about the necessary work to get a 64-bit build of Octave that runs on Windows OS is [here.](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/error-memory-exhausted-or-requested-size-too-large-for-range-of-Octave-s-index-type-trying-to-returnt-td4646032.html)

Answer (score 14):

According to Andrew Ng himself, `fmincg` is used not to get a more accurate result (remember, your cost function will be same in either case, and your hypothesis no simpler or more complex) but because it is more efficient at doing gradient descent for especially complex hypotheses.  He himself seems to use `fminunc` where the hypothesis have few features, but `fmincg` where it has hundreds.

Comment: When you say fewer terms, what do you mean by that? number of features and parameters?

Comment: `fmincg` works similarly to `fminunc`, but is more efficient when we are dealing with large number of parameters.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does fmincg work?

Here is a copy of the source code with comments explaining the various algorithms used.  It's a doozy, as it does the same thing a child's brain does when learning to discriminate between dog and chair.

This is the Octave source for fmincg.m.

```
function [X, fX, i] = fmincg(f, X, options, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5)
% Minimize a continuous differentialble multivariate function. Starting point
% is given by "X" (D by 1), and the function named in the string "f", must
% return a function value and a vector of partial derivatives. The Polack-
% Ribiere flavour of conjugate gradients is used to compute search directions,
% and a line search using quadratic and cubic polynomial approximations and the
% Wolfe-Powell stopping criteria is used together with the slope ratio method
% for guessing initial step sizes. Additionally a bunch of checks are made to
% make sure that exploration is taking place and that extrapolation will not
% be unboundedly large. The "length" gives the length of the run: if it is
% positive, it gives the maximum number of line searches, if negative its
% absolute gives the maximum allowed number of function evaluations. You can
% (optionally) give "length" a second component, which will indicate the
% reduction in function value to be expected in the first line-search (defaults
% to 1.0). The function returns when either its length is up, or if no further
% progress can be made (ie, we are at a minimum, or so close that due to
% numerical problems, we cannot get any closer). If the function terminates
% within a few iterations, it could be an indication that the function value
% and derivatives are not consistent (ie, there may be a bug in the
% implementation of your "f" function). The function returns the found
% solution "X", a vector of function values "fX" indicating the progress made
% and "i" the number of iterations (line searches or function evaluations,
% depending on the sign of "length") used.
%
% Usage: [X, fX, i] = fmincg(f, X, options, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5)
%
% See also: checkgrad
%
% Copyright (C) 2001 and 2002 by Carl Edward Rasmussen. Date 2002-02-13
%
%
% (C) Copyright 1999, 2000 & 2001, Carl Edward Rasmussen
%
% Permission is granted for anyone to copy, use, or modify these
% programs and accompanying documents for purposes of research or
% education, provided this copyright notice is retained, and note is
% made of any changes that have been made.
%
% These programs and documents are distributed without any warranty,
% express or implied.  As the programs were written for research
% purposes only, they have not been tested to the degree that would be
% advisable in any important application.  All use of these programs is
% entirely at the user's own risk.
%
% [ml-class] Changes Made:
% 1) Function name and argument specifications
% 2) Output display
%

% Read options
if exist('options', 'var') && ~isempty(options) && isfield(options, 'MaxIter')
    length = options.MaxIter;
else
    length = 100;
end

RHO = 0.01;                            % a bunch of constants for line searches
SIG = 0.5;       % RHO and SIG are the constants in the Wolfe-Powell conditions
INT = 0.1;    % don't reevaluate within 0.1 of the limit of the current bracket
EXT = 3.0;                    % extrapolate maximum 3 times the current bracket
MAX = 20;                         % max 20 function evaluations per line search
RATIO = 100;                                      % maximum allowed slope ratio

argstr = ['feval(f, X'];                      % compose string used to call function
for i = 1:(nargin - 3)
  argstr = [argstr, ',P', int2str(i)];
end
argstr = [argstr, ')'];

if max(size(length)) == 2, red=length(2); length=length(1); else red=1; end
S=['Iteration '];

i = 0;                                            % zero the run length counter
ls_failed = 0;                             % no previous line search has failed
fX = [];
[f1 df1] = eval(argstr);                      % get function value and gradient
i = i + (length<0);                                            % count epochs?!
s = -df1;                                        % search direction is steepest
d1 = -s'*s;                                                 % this is the slope
z1 = red/(1-d1);                                  % initial step is red/(|s|+1)

while i < abs(length)                                      % while not finished
  i = i + (length>0);                                      % count iterations?!

  X0 = X; f0 = f1; df0 = df1;                   % make a copy of current values
  X = X + z1*s;                                             % begin line search
  [f2 df2] = eval(argstr);
  i = i + (length<0);                                          % count epochs?!
  d2 = df2'*s;
  f3 = f1; d3 = d1; z3 = -z1;             % initialize point 3 equal to point 1
  if length>0, M = MAX; else M = min(MAX, -length-i); end
  success = 0; limit = -1;                     % initialize quanteties
  while 1
    while ((f2 > f1+z1*RHO*d1) | (d2 > -SIG*d1)) & (M > 0)
      limit = z1;                                         % tighten the bracket
      if f2 > f1
        z2 = z3 - (0.5*d3*z3*z3)/(d3*z3+f2-f3);                 % quadratic fit
      else
        A = 6*(f2-f3)/z3+3*(d2+d3);                                 % cubic fit
        B = 3*(f3-f2)-z3*(d3+2*d2);
        z2 = (sqrt(B*B-A*d2*z3*z3)-B)/A;       % numerical error possible - ok!
      end
      if isnan(z2) | isinf(z2)
        z2 = z3/2;                  % if we had a numerical problem then bisect
      end
      z2 = max(min(z2, INT*z3),(1-INT)*z3);  % don't accept too close to limits
      z1 = z1 + z2;                                           % update the step
      X = X + z2*s;
      [f2 df2] = eval(argstr);
      M = M - 1; i = i + (length<0);                           % count epochs?!
      d2 = df2'*s;
      z3 = z3-z2;                    % z3 is now relative to the location of z2
    end
    if f2 > f1+z1*RHO*d1 | d2 > -SIG*d1
      break;                                                % this is a failure
    elseif d2 > SIG*d1
      success = 1; break;                                             % success
    elseif M == 0
      break;                                                          % failure
    end
    A = 6*(f2-f3)/z3+3*(d2+d3);                      % make cubic extrapolation
    B = 3*(f3-f2)-z3*(d3+2*d2);
    z2 = -d2*z3*z3/(B+sqrt(B*B-A*d2*z3*z3));        % num. error possible - ok!
    if ~isreal(z2) | isnan(z2) | isinf(z2) | z2 < 0   % num prob or wrong sign?
      if limit < -0.5                               % if we have no upper limit
        z2 = z1 * (EXT-1);                 % the extrapolate the maximum amount
      else
        z2 = (limit-z1)/2;                                   % otherwise bisect
      end
    elseif (limit > -0.5) & (z2+z1 > limit)          % extraplation beyond max?
      z2 = (limit-z1)/2;                                               % bisect
    elseif (limit < -0.5) & (z2+z1 > z1*EXT)       % extrapolation beyond limit
      z2 = z1*(EXT-1.0);                           % set to extrapolation limit
    elseif z2 < -z3*INT
      z2 = -z3*INT;
    elseif (limit > -0.5) & (z2 < (limit-z1)*(1.0-INT))   % too close to limit?
      z2 = (limit-z1)*(1.0-INT);
    end
    f3 = f2; d3 = d2; z3 = -z2;                  % set point 3 equal to point 2
    z1 = z1 + z2; X = X + z2*s;                      % update current estimates
    [f2 df2] = eval(argstr);
    M = M - 1; i = i + (length<0);                             % count epochs?!
    d2 = df2'*s;
  end                                                      % end of line search

  if success                                         % if line search succeeded
    f1 = f2; fX = [fX' f1]';
    fprintf('%s %4i | Cost: %4.6e\r', S, i, f1);
    s = (df2'*df2-df1'*df2)/(df1'*df1)*s - df2;      % Polack-Ribiere direction
    tmp = df1; df1 = df2; df2 = tmp;                         % swap derivatives
    d2 = df1'*s;
    if d2 > 0                                      % new slope must be negative
      s = -df1;                              % otherwise use steepest direction
      d2 = -s'*s;
    end
    z1 = z1 * min(RATIO, d1/(d2-realmin));          % slope ratio but max RATIO
    d1 = d2;
    ls_failed = 0;                              % this line search did not fail
  else
    X = X0; f1 = f0; df1 = df0;  % restore point from before failed line search
    if ls_failed | i > abs(length)          % line search failed twice in a row
      break;                             % or we ran out of time, so we give up
    end
    tmp = df1; df1 = df2; df2 = tmp;                         % swap derivatives
    s = -df1;                                                    % try steepest
    d1 = -s'*s;
    z1 = 1/(1-d1);
    ls_failed = 1;                                    % this line search failed
  end
  if exist('OCTAVE_VERSION')
    fflush(stdout);
  end
end
fprintf('\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

fmincg uses the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)

If you look at the picture at this link, you will see that the CG method converges much faster than fminunc, but it assumes a number of constraints which I think are not required in the fminunc method ([BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm)) (conjugate vectors vs non-conjugate vectors).

In other words, the fmincg method is faster but more coarse than fminunc, so it works better for huge matrices (many features, like thousands) vs smaller ones with up to hundreds of features.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**fmincg is more accurate than fminunc. Time taken by both of them is almost same.In Neural Network or in general which has more no of weights fminunc can give out of memory error.So fmincg is more memory efficient.**

Using fminunc, accuracy is 93.10 and time taken is 11.3794 seconds.

```
Testing lrCostFunction() with regularization
Cost: 2.534819
Expected cost: 2.534819
Gradients:
 0.146561
 -0.548558
 0.724722
 1.398003
Expected gradients:
 0.146561
 -0.548558
 0.724722
 1.398003
Program paused. Press enter to continue.

Training One-vs-All Logistic Regression...
id = 1512324857357
Elapsed time is 11.3794 seconds.
Program paused. Press enter to continue.

Training Set Accuracy: 93.100000
```

Using fmincg, accuracy is 95.12 and time taken is 11.7978 seconds.

```
Testing lrCostFunction() with regularization
Cost: 2.534819
Expected cost: 2.534819
Gradients:
 0.146561
 -0.548558
 0.724722
 1.398003
Expected gradients:
 0.146561
 -0.548558
 0.724722
 1.398003
Program paused. Press enter to continue.

Training One-vs-All Logistic Regression...
id = 1512325280047
Elapsed time is 11.7978 seconds.

Training Set Accuracy: 95.120000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using fmincg to optimize the cost function.fmincg works similarly to fminunc, but is more efficient when we are dealing with a large number of parameters. Your cost function will be same in either case, and your hypothesis no simpler or more complex) but because it is more efficient at doing gradient descent for especially complex hypotheses.

It used for efficient memory utilization.

Comment: Congratulations on your first SO answer!  To improve your answer a little more you could link to some evidence or documentation supporting what you have described.

Answer (score 0):

fmincg is an internal function developed by course on Coursera, unlike fminunc, which is inbuilt Octave function. Since they both are used for logistic regression, they only differ in one aspect. When the number of parameters to be considered is considerably large (if or not compared to the size of the training set), fmincg works faster and processes more accurately than fminunc. And, fminunc is preferred when there are no restrictions (unconstrained) on the parameters being passed to it.